# [JAVA} A-Star code isn't finding optimal Path

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to code A* search algorithm but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm copying the pseudocode from wikipedia. My code seems to just search every possible node. Here's my showPath() function:

```
public void showPath() {
Nodes current = end;

while(current.cameFrom!=null) {
    current.isPath = true;
    current = current.cameFrom;
}
}
```

The start node will have a cameFrom of null since that's it's default value.

```
public void A_Star() {
PriorityQueue<Nodes> closedSet = new PriorityQueue<Nodes>();
PriorityQueue<Nodes> openSet = new PriorityQueue<Nodes>();
closedSet.clear();
openSet.clear();

start.gScore = 0;
openSet.add(start);
start.fScore = getDist(start,end);

while(!(openSet.size() ==0)) {
    Nodes curr = openSet.poll();
    if(curr.x == end.x && curr.y == end.y) {
        showPath();
    }
    closedSet.add(curr);
    for(int i=0;i<curr.getNeighbourCount();i++) {
        Nodes neighbour = curr.getNeighbour(i);
        if(closedSet.contains(neighbour)) {
            continue;
        }
        //isPassable is a boolean that is false if the Nodes is an obstacle
        if(!openSet.contains(neighbour) && neighbour.isPassable) {
            openSet.add(neighbour);
        }
        //It's a grid so every point is a distance of 1 from it's neighbours
        else if((curr.gScore+1)>= neighbour.gScore){
            continue;
        }
        neighbour.cameFrom = curr;
        neighbour.gScore = curr.gScore+1;
        neighbour.fScore = neighbour.gScore + getDist(neighbour,end);

    }

}
```

}

EDIT: My getDist function

```
public int getDist(Nodes node1, Nodes node2) {
    return ( Math.abs(node1.x - node2.x) + Math.abs(node1.y - node2.y));
}
```

Comment: Hi, it might be a good idea to tag this as an algorithm as well as a java question.

Comment: what is your distance function, getDist?

Comment: It returns manhatten distance.   
return ( Math.abs(node1.x - node2.x) + Math.abs(node1.y - node2.y));

Comment: @FarhaanMithagare try Eucleadian distance.

Comment: @FarhaanMithagare and result?

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry, Euclidean distance gave the same output. Literally the same. I assumed it was something to do with maybe how I initialized the 2D array but I just gave up and decided to use a different approach for my project.

Comment: @FarhaanMithagare the Manhattan Distance in a grid will cause all possible forward paths has equal length. I would have like to see the full code and the test area. Anyway. Goodluck.

Comment: @kelalaka I realized that once you sent the picture. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at this [picure](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-8d64c8344fc8364e46b9712e2c51dca4), you have to notice that, with Manhatten distance, all of the paths from start to the goal has equal distances. This will cause that, you will visit all.

Change your distance to Euclidean Distance.